# All AWS Route 53 Alias options greyed out

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53, cname

When trying to create a new Route 53 record and enabling **Alias**, all options under "**Route traffic to**" except for "another record in this hosted zone" are greyed out and unavailable to select. I am trying to point a CNAME to my active ELB, but cannot select "**Alias to Application and Classic Load Balancer**"

Any reason all the options would be disabled? Account permissions? Security settings?

Comment: Needs to be an A record instead of CNAME.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jordanm is correct: Needs to be an A record instead of CNAME - Thanks!